# Dynamic population of tabs

Tags: tkinter, tabs

I have a list of tab names that can change so I want to loop through the names and create the tabs. From those, I want to place various buttons that vary depending on the tab that a user clicks. My problem is that my tabs don't load. If I remove the command, my window loads fine with the correct tabs.

My code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def loadtab(event):
    selection = event.widget.select()
    tabN = event.widget.tab(selection, "text")
    t_nos=str(uFrame.index(uFrame.select())+1)
    tab = f'tab{t_nos}'

    if tabN == 'Ed':
        tk.Button(tab, text=tabN).pack()
    elif tabN == 'Ted':
        tk.Button(tab, text=tabN).pack()

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Tab")

uFrame = ttk.Notebook(root, style="TFrame") #Create notebook
uFrame.pack(pady=20)
uFrame.bind("<<NotebookTabChanged>>", loadtab) #Bind notebook so that when it is changed, it loads items onto each tab

pathOpt = ['Ed', 'Ted'] #Tab names
tNo = 0 #Counter
for name in pathOpt: #parse through tab names and create tabs
    tab = f'tab{tNo + 1}'
    tab = ttk.Frame(uFrame)
    uFrame.add(tab, text=pathOpt[tNo])
    tNo += 1

test = tk.Button(root, text='Deliniate tabs') # placeholder to show where tabs are
test.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Results:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cwade\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\PyProjects\TemplateTool\TemplateToolV3_Tabs.py", line 12, in loadtab
    tk.Button(tab, text=tabN).pack()
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\cwade\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2707, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'button', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\cwade\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2623, in __init__
    self._setup(master, cnf)
  File "C:\Users\cwade\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2592, in _setup  
    self.tk = master.tk
              ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

I have printed the various names etc. and found the tab name to be correct but I still get the error.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `loadtab()`, you assign `tab` variable a string and then use it as the parent of the newly created button.  It causes the exception.

You need to get the instance of the frame using `.nametowidget()`:

```py
def loadtab(event):
    # selection is the name of the frame
    selection = event.widget.select()
    tabN = event.widget.tab(selection, "text")
    #t_nos=str(uFrame.index(uFrame.select())+1)
    #tab = f'tab{t_nos}'
    # get the instance of the frame using .nametowidget()
    tab = event.widget.nametowidget(selection)

    tk.Button(tab, text=tabN).pack()
```

Comment: Thank you acw1668, that worked a treat. I understand what I did wrong. Cheers.